# npm equivalent of pip install -e

Tags: npm, installation, pip

In python I can install package in "editable" mode with

```
pip install -e .
```

Which means the code from current directory will be installed computer-wide, but still be able to edit code and access it from other project without re-installation.

Is it possible to do the same with `npm`?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `npm link`.
You first need to create a global simlink and then link it in the project you are currently working on.

```
cd ~/projects/node-redis    # go into the package directory
npm link                    # creates global link
cd ~/projects/node-bloggy   # go into some other package directory.
npm link redis              # link-install the package
```

There is an article about it [here](https://cd%20%7E/projects/some-dep%20npm%20link%20%20#%20Step%201.%20cd%20%7E/projects/my-app%20npm%20link%20some-dep%20%20#%20Step%202.).
Here is a linke to the  [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-link)